# not able to install Nvidia Driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPlwS.png)

as the picture states I'm having a problem switching Display drivers. The only one i touched during install was broadcom so im trying to figure this any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the use of Nvidia drivers from the Nvidia website. If you installed manual drivers then you cannot change it from the pacakge manager.

Comment: Oddly enough i was running 18.04.2 i upgraded to 19.04 and I'm no longer seeing this porblem running 418 isn't the latest but at least im not stuck.

Comment: it's not odd. it'd because 19.04 uses the ppa drivers out of the box. it's been a  long time coming obvisouly, as you can see it's a choice that is highly beneficial to newer users. please upvote and mark as answer (checkmark) Ijlal Haider, he gave the correct answer.